# Stream realtime data to Spacy model

Tags: spacy

I'm Having difficulties streaming data to a custom Spacy model. I have a real-time data stream from Twitter and would like the data processed. I have read through Spacy documentation and no article specifies how to process real-time data. I already have code to store processed data in JSON format but need help with setting up a way to process data as they come.

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: I was having issues processing serialized data to a spacy model. I however managed to process large datasets using Kafka.